# The Ins and Outs of Setters and Getters in iOS?

Tags: ios, oop

From what I can understand setters and getters are used to set variable values from outside of the class scope. This seems useful as you may want to hide code using encapsulation.

However surely this method goes against encapsulation theory as you are injecting and manipulating values from outside of the class?

When are the correct times to use setters and getters in OOP? (any analogies would be great)

Are they defined in the main file or the interface file? As it seems like you would want to define a setter and getter in the .h file as you then set the variable's actual use in the .m file.

Lastly, why do you see getter methods simply returning the variable that they are getting? surely this is already done by the main file implementation.

Overall I just want a real clarification of getters and setters and why they are so useful.

Thankyou

Comment: Read a tutorial. Read a book. Read mine, even. http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/

Answer (score 2):

If you have both - setter and getter - for one variable, it is true, that you can change it outside your class.

There is right question - why to do that?

Because of reusability and "agility" of your code.

**1)Checking for right input**

If you want to set age of person, you can check if the value is greater than zero in setter.

**2) Reusability**

Imagine that you create program which (among others) connect to server, receive array of bits and it creates integer from that array. Then you do something with that integer, you set this value from several places.

But server changes sending from little-endian to big. If you used setter and getter, you can change setter to transform it right before saving it. Or you can change your getter for giving right output.

Comment: So a setter is in theory a class of it's own however the class's object is the variable from within a seperate class?

Comment: No, setters and getters are plain instance methods / functions, making instance variables accessible (read / write) and possibly involving resulting actions.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say there's no "wrong" time to use setters and getters because they give you additional control (memory management etc). As libik mentioned validation of values is really important to prevent your program from "falling" into an inconsistent state no matter if you set a self-calculated value or user input. And using setters often does not just mean storing a value in an ivar but might lead to other actions being necessary when setting a value. Hiding code is important as you don't want to make all actions behind the scenes obvious to public. And a setter also gives you the chance to return e.g. a boolean value representing if the value could be set properly or not.

A getter gives you the oppurtunity to lazily instantiate an object "on demand" if it hasn't been done yet instead of always creating objects supposing they could be needed later.

```
- (Object *) myObject {
    if (!_myObject) {
        _myObject = [[Object alloc] init];
    }
    return _myObject;
}
```

It's up to your needs whether you define your setters and getters in the interface of the .h or .m file. There might be a case in which you want your setter to be private (in .m file) and only make your getter public because the value is beeing changed inside your implementation depending on certain state changes or vice versa.

Comment: You may not want all your data upfront and available on a public level and so you can use getters and setters in order to instantiate a variable in private and use the setter method therefore to change it’s implemented variable value behind the scenes as and when you feel the need to. Am i correct in saying this?

Comment: Yes, your're right. Suppose you have a dice class with an instance method playDice which calculates the dice's new value based on a random number algorithm. So it would not make sense to make the setter or even the ivar public to make the value mutable from outside the dice's class scope. But it does make sense to make the getter public in order to make the value readable from outside.